# Binfmt config not persisting after booting

Tags: dual-boot, mono, kernel-modules

I have the binfmt kernel module set up so I can run .NET apps as if they were native binaries.

I have the /etc/rc.local file configured identically to [this](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/mono.txt).

If I power down my computer or boot into Windows, when I come back to Ubuntu, I can't run .NET apps without calling Mono.  However, if I simply `touch /etc/rc.local` and restart, the binfmt configuration appears to kick in and I can run my .NET EXE's as I expect to.

How do I get my configuration to stick?

Answer (score 1):

binfmt formats are typically handled by **binfmt-support** package. When mono is installed in Ubuntu, it adds a cli format specification in /var/lib/binfmts/cli.

binfmt-support is configured to start automatically at boot. I'd suggest checking, that you have binfmt-support and mono-runtime packages in your system.